# How to delete a linked list in C?

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, malloc, free

I am trying to create a linked list in c with the following def:

```
/**
 * The definition of node and linked list.
 */
typedef struct _node{
    void * val;
    struct _node * next;
} node;

typedef struct{
    node * head;
} linkedlist;
```

And I have a function to delete it entirely(not for a sigle node, but the whole list):

```
void clean_list(linkedlist * ll){
    node * temp;
    curr = ll->head;

    while(ll->curr->next != NULL){
    temp = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    free(temp->val);
    free(temp);
    }
}
```

My question is:

- Does it work?
- How do I know if it actually work or not?

I am working on a MacBook Pro and using gcc as the compiler.

Comment: Did you try it?  What about stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: What's the purpose of `curr` in `linkedlist`?

Comment: I compiled it and it works fine but my question is how do I know if it really free the memory I created(malloc).

Comment: The curr pointer is just a free pointer for the current node you are working with. Please ignore it if you find it strange to you.

Comment: @dorafmon - add some logging or use a debugger if you don't believe it works.

Comment: Best way to see if this code works? Write an `int main()` method!

Comment: @ecbrodie I have a entire test.c file to test it. Want me to post it here?

Comment: @CarlNorum How can the debugger help me to see if I freed all the memory I created? Sorry I am a little bit confused here.

Comment: You can use valgrind to see if you properly freed all allocated memory

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yeah that would be better.

Comment: @dorafmon this list isn't circular, right? just a plain linked list?

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah just a singly linked list.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Your code accesses `ll->curr`, which doesn't exist. If it really does compile for you, don't you think you should post the actual code that compiled?

Comment: @CharlesSalvia I used it on a simple Hello World program and the summary gives me 
==46940== LEAK SUMMARY:

==46940==    definitely lost: 8,624 bytes in 14 blocks

==46940==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks

==46940==      possibly lost: 4,941 bytes in 67 blocks

==46940==    still reachable: 48,227 bytes in 277 blocks

==46940==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==46940== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory

So I think I cannot trust it.

Comment: @JonathanWood, `ll->curr` existed in the original post, I don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: @JonathanWood Now its right I think

Comment: @CarlNorum because I realized it would be better if it is local to the function.

Comment: Ok. one more question. is the struct pointed to by `ll` (the linked list struct) **also** dynamically allocated?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes. ll->head->val = malloc(sth here)

Comment: Not what I asked.. *Is the **linkedlist** structure itself (the memory pointed to by `ll` on function entry) also dynamically allocated?* I can already see the data pointer within the node is such.

Comment: No, I declare it when I use a linked list and then use create_list(&mylinklist) to create it and clean_list(&mylinklist) to destroy it.

Answer (score 2):

I will never understand why people who have code that compiles will post code that doesn't compile. But, assuming the linkedlist itself needs to be freed, here's how I'd approach it (untested):

```
void clean_list(linkedlist *pll)
{
    node *pnext;

    for (node *pnode = pll->head; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnext)
    {
        pnext = pnode->next;
        free(pnode->val);
        free(pnode);
    }
    free(pll);
}
```

Comment: You may have changed it but the code in your question will still not compile. If you were to post the code as I suggested, you would not edit, you'd simply use copy and paste. At any rate, I moved past that. I've presented the code for how I would clean up such a linkedlist.

Answer (score 0):

```
void clean_list(linkedlist * ll){
    node *temp, **ppp;

    for (ppp= &ll->head; temp = *ppp;   ){
      *ppp = temp->next;
      free(temp->val);
      free(temp);
      }
}
```